# Can some please clarify the rules of stress for me?

Tags: style

I was having trouble determining which words are stresed.

How do you tell the words that are stressed from the words that are unstressed?

Thank you.

Comment: [Which kind of stress](https://www.thoughtco.com/esl-intonation-stress-types-1212091)?

Comment: The kind that you pronounce out loud or in your mind when you read a sentence, without stressing anything for any other purpose than pronouncing the sentence, the way it is written.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't notice that your comment was a link. I think I mean tonic stress.

Comment: Listen to it in your mind's ear. If you don't hear it, for sure your readers won't.

Comment: My issue is not that I don't have an inner ear which can distinguish between stress and non-stress. My issue is that I wasn't certain which words were partially or totally stressed and which words were not stressed at all.

Comment: Since I looked it up, I already know, but for the sake of everyone else here, I posted this question.

Comment: @garbus Posting a question you already know the answer to and then not answering it yourself isn't really in the spirit of Stack Exchange. If you know the answer, would you consider self-answering?